# Binary search is not working for the following Double Linked List Data Structure (probably needs to be sorted)

Tags: c#, csv, data-structures

I am trying to binary search a string from a CSV file. The binary search is to be used on the double linked list I made. The issue which I think it is, is that the information has to be sorted for binary search but I am quite stuck on that since I am pretty new into data structures. I will mark out the binary search so it's easily identifiable. Linear search works if it's of any help. To elaborate some more it can not find the string I give it.

**Double linked list code:**

```
public class DLL
{
    /*The double linked list, it has a head pointer pointing to the first node and a tail pointer which is pointing
        at the last node. The count field keeps track of how many nodes are in the list.
    */
    
    public Node headNode;
    public Node tailNode;
    public int countNodes;

    public int CountNodes
    {
        get { return this.countNodes; }
    }

    public void AddLastNode(string color)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node(color);

        if (this.headNode == null)
        {
            headNode = newNode;
            tailNode = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            newNode.prevNode = this.tailNode; //from the Node class prevNode
            this.tailNode.nextNode = newNode;
            this.tailNode = newNode;
        }

        this.countNodes++;
    }
    
    //Get the node index
    private Node getNodeIndex(int i)
    {
        if (i < 0 || i >= this.countNodes)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        }

        Node currNode = this.headNode;
        int currI = 0;

        while (currI < i)
        {
            currNode = currNode.nextNode; //nextNode from the Node Class
            currI++;
        }

        return currNode;
    }

    public int binarySearch(string colorBs) //BINARY SEARCH HERE!!
    {
        if(headNode== null)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        int st = 0;
        int end = this.countNodes - 1;

        while (st <= end)
        {
            int m = (st + end) / 2;
            Node mNode = getNodeIndex(m);

            int comparison = string.Compare(colorBs, mNode.color, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

            if (comparison == 0)
            {
                return m;
            }else if (comparison < 0)
            {
                end = m - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                st = m + 1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int linearSearch(string colorLs)
    {
        if (headNode == null)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        Node currNode = headNode;
        int i = 0;

        while (currNode != null)
        {
            if (String.Equals(colorLs, currNode.color, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) ///ignore capital or small letters, treat it as the same
            {
                return i;
            }

            currNode = currNode.nextNode;
            i++;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void trFwd() //Traversing Forward
    {
        Node currNode = this.headNode;

        while (currNode != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(currNode.color);
            currNode = currNode.nextNode;
        }
    }

    public void trBwd() //Traversing Backwards
    {
        Node currNode = this.tailNode;

        while (currNode != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(currNode.color);
            currNode = currNode.prevNode;
        }
    } 
}
```

**Node**

```
public class Node
{
    //Proprieties for the node data which is the color of type string and pointers to the next and previous node
    public string color { get; set; }
    public Node nextNode { get; set; }
    public Node prevNode { get; set; }

    public Node(string color)
    {
        this.color = color;
        this.nextNode = null;
        this.prevNode = null;
    }
```

**CSV class**

```
namespace DoubleLinkedList;

public class CsvS
{
    private DLL dll;

    public CsvS()
    {
        this.dll = new DLL();
    }

    public DLL getDll()
    {
        return this.dll;
    }

    public void nodeBuilder(string pathCsv)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pathCsv))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] fields = line.Split(','); 
                if(fields.Length>=2)
                {
                    string fieldValue = fields[1].Trim();
                    dll.AddLastNode(fieldValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int binarySearchCsv(string colorBs)
    {
        return dll.binarySearch(colorBs);
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using DoubleLinkedList;

CsvS csv = new CsvS();
csv.nodeBuilder("colors.csv");

string searchColor = "Black";
int position = csv.binarySearchCsv(searchColor);

if (position != -1)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Position of '{searchColor}' is {position}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"'{searchColor}' not found !");
}

Console.WriteLine("Traversing fwd:");
csv.getDll().trFwd();

Console.WriteLine("Traversing bwd:");
csv.getDll().trBwd();
```

Comment: I would change the name DLL -- it's often used for Dynamic Linked Library, and to me, it's just confusing!

Comment: Your binary search will only work if the link list is sorted.  You are dividing the list by 2 and then checking if the color is greater than or less than the middle item.  You also have to be careful when there is an even number of items in the list.  For example if there is two items in the list where is N/2.

Comment: Binary search on a linked list is useless. Even if the list is sorted, it has a time complexity of O(log) which obviously is worse than a linear scan.

Comment: @trincot Yep, I agree on that. BinarySearch needs to access items directly by index. Jumping through all the elements to navigate becomes very slow.

Comment: What do you think then about interpolation search in this case to be replaced with binary search?

Comment: @CatCoderInHisUniDays, also interpolation search is intended to be used with **arrays**,  i.e. where you have access to an element at a given index in **constant** time. This is not the case with linked lists. The only search method that makes any sense in linked lists is linear search. Whereever the node is that has the value you want to find, you'll have to "walk" to that node from one node to the next, and that is exactly what a linear search does. There is no way to optimise this unless you change the data structure (like to a skiplist).

Comment: I just went with sentinel linear search and it worked. Yeah the data is not sorted so I went ahead with this one.

Comment: *"Yeah the data is not sorted, so..."*: even if it would be sorted, you need linear search. Did you get that point? There is no other way to traverse a list than ... linear.